# Why do I get InputMismatchException in my Java programme?

Tags: java, eclipse, methods, switch-statement, java.util.scanner

I have made a dog `kennel/pound` in Java that is working (in eclipse). But when I test it I get this `InputMismatchException`. 
Is it something wrong with the way I did the `switch-statement` and the cases? Or something with my `Scanner`? The program is compiling so I don't understand.
One of the requirements in the assignment is for the program to accept these commands:

- register new dog
- increase age
- list dogs
- remove dog
- exit

Another requirement is that the test program must identify the word "Error".
Please help me!!!

Here is the Dog class:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Dog {

    private String dogName;
    private String dogRace;
    private int dogAge;
    private double dogWeight;

    public Dog(String name, String race, int age, double weight){
    this.dogName = name;
    this.dogRace = race;
    this.dogAge = age;
    this.dogWeight = weight;
    }

    public String getDogName (){ 
        return this.dogName;
    }
    public String getDogRace (){
        return this.dogRace;
    }
    public void birthday(){
        dogAge = dogAge+1;
    }
    public int getDogAge(){
        return this.dogAge;
    }
    public double getDogWeight(){
        return this.dogWeight;
    }
    public double getDogTailLength(){
        if (!getDogRace().equalsIgnoreCase("Tax"))
        if(!getDogRace().equalsIgnoreCase("Dachshund")){
            return ((dogAge * dogWeight)/ 10);

        }
        return 3.7;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return "Name: " + getDogName() + ", Race: " + getDogRace() + ", Age: " + getDogAge() + ", Weight: " + 
                getDogWeight() + ", Tail: " + getDogTailLength();

    }
}
```

And here is the Main class:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {

    public static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    private ArrayList <Dog> dogList = new ArrayList<Dog>();

    public ArrayList<Dog> getDogList(){
        return this.dogList;
    }

    public String dogMenu(){
        return "Choose a commande below: \n1) Register new dog \n2) Increase age \n3) List dogs \n4)"
                    + " Remove dog \n5) Exit ";
    }
    public String error(){
        return "ERROR: please choose a number between 1-5";
    }
    public void addDog(){
        System.out.println("1- Enter the dogs name: ");
        String name = scan.next();
        System.out.println("2- Enter the dogs race: ");
        String race = scan.next();
        System.out.println("3- Enter the dogs age: ");
        int age = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("4- Enter the dogs weight: ");
        double weight = scan.nextDouble();
        Dog newDog = new Dog(name, race, age, weight);
        getDogList().add(newDog);
        System.out.println(newDog);

    }

    public void ageDog(){
        System.out.println("Which dog would you like to age? (State the name): ");
        String write = scan.next();
        for(Dog d: getDogList()){
            if(d.getDogName().equalsIgnoreCase(write)){
                d.birthday();
            }else{
                System.out.println("ERROR: The dog doesn't exist in the kennel");

            }
        }
    }

    public void dogTail(){
        System.out.println("State the tail length: ");
        double dogTailLengthIn = scan.nextDouble();
        for(Dog d1: getDogList()){ 
            if(d1.getDogTailLength()>= dogTailLengthIn){
                System.out.println(d1);
            }
        }
        if(getDogList().isEmpty()){
            System.out.println("ERROR: There are no dogs!!!");

    }   

    }
    public void deleteDog(){
        System.out.println("Which dog do you want to delete? (State the name): ");
        String nameIn = scan.next();
        boolean delete = false; 
        for(int a = 0; a <getDogList().size();a++){
            if(getDogList().get(a).getDogName().equalsIgnoreCase(nameIn)){
                getDogList().remove(a);
                delete = true;
            }
        }
        if(delete){
            System.out.println("The dog " + nameIn + " is deleted from the register.");
        }else{
            System.out.println("The dog " + nameIn + " doesn't exist in the register.");
        }
    }
    public void exit(){
        System.out.println("Thank you. Hope to see you soon!");
        scan.close();
        System.exit(0);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){

        /*      Dog betty = new Dog("pudel", "Betty", 4, 22, 1.5); 

        Dog jonte = new Dog("rotweiler", "Jontis", 8, 60, 2);

        Dog jonas = new Dog("chihuahua", "Jonis", 2, 5, 0.3);*/

        Main kennel = new Main();

        while (true){ 
            System.out.print(kennel.dogMenu());
            int write = scan.nextInt();

            switch(write){

            case 1: 
                kennel.addDog();
                break; 

            case 2:
                kennel.ageDog();
                break;

            case 3:
                kennel.dogTail();
                break;

            case 4:
                kennel.deleteDog();
                break;

            case 5:
                kennel.exit();
            default: 
                System.out.println(kennel.error());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the problem:

```
Choose a commande below:
1) Register new dog
2) Increase age
3) List dogs
4) Remove dog
5) Exit

[IN:wrong command]
    java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException [LOOKING FOR: Any of [[fel case insensitive], [error case insensitive]]]
    [ERR: Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
      at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)
      at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
      at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
      at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
      at Main.main(Main.java:96)]
```

I get exactly this in every case!!

Comment: Please add the complete stack trace to your question, and indicate what line is throwing the excetion.

Comment: I am really new at this...but Iv'e linked a picture in the comment below!

Comment: for what input it is giving you the error?

Comment: where are you running it?

Comment: Are you literally typing "register new dog"?

Comment: @rebecka544 That's not a comment, it's an answer, and you shouldn't put pieces of your question in either place.  You need to [edit] your question to add information to it.  Also keep in mind that a picture of your error is not the same thing as your error.  You need to paste the appropriately formatted text into your question, not just a picture of it.

Comment: I did the program in Eclipse. But this is a school assignment and to pass it I have to test it in VPL. And the program works perfectly fine to run in both eclipse and VPL but when VPL evaluate my programme (based on the requirements I've listed in my question) I get InputMismatchException...that is why I am confused

Comment: No...I'm not typing "new dog" to add a new dog...I just press 1 and it adds a dog, if that is what you mean!

Answer (score 0):

You are getting `InputMismatchException` because you are typing a `String` as an input but `int write = scan.nextInt();` is expecting an `int` value from the `user`, so there is a `mismatch` of `datatype`. You code will work fine if you type the number of the option and not the `string` but still you need to change it for the input `Error`

Comment: Call me stupid...but I don't get it.:( What should I do??

Comment: I don't see the code to have this issue. Can you point out where you see it?

Comment: @isaace In the `main` method of `Main` class, the program is expecting an `integer input` from the user at line `int write = scan.nextInt();` Whenever the input from the user will be other than `int`, it'll give `InputMismatchException` like in case of `Error`

Comment: @rebecka544 you need to change the code to handle the `String` inputs also. Use ` String write = scan.next();` and change your logic of switch w.r.t. the `String` input. I'll suggest using `BufferReader` instead of `Scanner`

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that when VPL is testing your program, it's giving invalid inputs to test that you're handling invalid inputs correctly.  And you aren't.

If you have learned about `try` and `catch` blocks, this would be a good time to implement that knowledge and catch the error so you can properly handle it.

Comment: Yes I know about try and catch but don't know where to place it...I'm not really good at this, I'm a beginner...

Comment: The `try` block should contain the line of code that might give the error (which is the line containing `scan.nextInt();`).  The `catch` block should contain the code that says what to do if you get an error.  (I assume you should just do `System.out.println(kennel.error());` like you do in the `default` case.)

Answer (score 0):

You are getting  InputMismatchException because you are asking for a int from user in your Main class. Check for the below line in your public static void main(String[] args)

> int write = scan.nextInt();

If you enter anything else then integer, it will throw exception.
You can add a try catch block to handle the unwanted inputs. It should look something like the below. This will handle the inputs which are not integer and will give the user option to select a proper input.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Main kennel = new Main();
    while (true) {
        try {
            System.out.print(kennel.dogMenu() + "\n");
            int write = scan.nextInt();
            switch (write) {
            case 1:
                kennel.addDog();
                break;
            case 2:
                kennel.ageDog();
                break;
            case 3:
                kennel.dogTail();
                break;
            case 4:
                kennel.deleteDog();
                break;
            case 5:
                kennel.exit();
            default:
                System.out.println(kennel.error());
            }

        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            System.out.println(kennel.error());
            scan.nextLine();
        }
    }
}
```

I am not sure, what you mean by this "Another requirement is that the test program must identify the word "Error". Please help me!!!". If you can provide more input, I can try to help.